# Jquery replace \n with <br />?

Tags: jquery, replace, tags

How can I change this script to replace `\n` with `<br />` :

```
$("<span />", { html: this.value, "class":"view" }).insertAfter(this);
```

I try this but now working ? :

```
$("<span />", { html: this.value.replace("\n", "<br />"), "class":"view" }).insertAfter(this);
```

This replace only first `\n` in SPAN but not all `\n` tags in SPAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following code

```
this.value.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('#input').val().replace("\n", "<br />", "g")
```

Replace with global scope

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does only for 1st instance.

for all you should use **`global identifier`** like

```
this.value.replace("\n", "<br />", "g")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("<span />", { html: this.value.replace("/\\n/", "<br />"), "class":"view" }).insertAfter(this);
```

For more you can check this

```
<?php
$str = "\n deeepu \n kilimanoor \n \n tvm \n kerala india";
$nstr = preg_replace('/\\n/', '<br>', $str);
echo "$nstr";
?>
```